# Removing first character from a column if it starts with 0

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, visual-studio, select

I have an oracle table, `a_abc` that have three columns (`name`, `ID` and `address`). The data for this table will be extracted from a txt file. How to remove the first character in ID column if it starts with number '0'. I need a VB solution. This is what Ive done so far now

```
Private Sub ReadData()
    Dim rowvalue As String
    Dim cellvalue(20) As String
    Dim header As String = "ID"
    Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader("D:\local_costctr.txt")
    'Reading CSV file content 
    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
        rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
        cellvalue = rowvalue.Split("|") 'check what is ur separator

        ConnectOracle()
        mySQLcmd.Connection = myConn

        If SQL.Length > 0 Then
            SQL.Replace(SQL.ToString, "")
        End If

        SQL.Append("insert into a_abc (name ,ID ,address)  ")
        SQL.Append(" values ('" & cellvalue(0) & "' ,'" & cellvalue(1) & "','" & cellvalue(2) & "') ")


        Console.WriteLine(header)
        Console.WriteLine(header.Trim({"0"c}))          


        Try
            mySQLcmd.CommandText = SQL.ToString
            mySQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

    End While
End Sub
```

If there is more than one leading zero, I want all of them removed.

Comment: Please try to be more detailed: do you need a solution in Oracle or in VB? what have you tried so far? are you having an unexpected result or an error? Please post your table strcture and the relevant part of your code where you are trying to remove the first char.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the ID value has more than one leading zero?

Comment: @Aleksej I need the solution in VB. Ive updated my question, please check it

Comment: @APC If there is more than one leading zero, i want it to be removed too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ltrim`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions083.htm) function should do the trick:

```
SELECT name, LTRIM(id, '0'), address
FROM   a_abc
```

EDIT:
Now that the question was edited, I see you refer inserting the data, not querying it. The same solution could be applied on an `insert` too though:

```
SQL.Append("insert into a_abc (name ,ID ,address)  ")
SQL.Append(" values ('" & cellvalue(0) & "', LTRIM(" & cellvalue(1) & ", '0'), '" & cellvalue(2) & "') ")
```

Comment: This is the neatest solution, because SQL. However, looking at the OP's code I suspect they want VB code.

Comment: @APC Just saw the edited question. I'd still leave the trimming to the database, even via VB - see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

While you are extracting the data from the txt-file and you come across the ID-field:

```
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("yourpath")
        If "myID".Substring(0, 1) = "0" Then
            'take the "myID" without the leading 0
            "myID".Substring(1)  
        End if   
    Next
```

Depending on your case you might need Null-checks etc...

Edited for your code: 
Replace cellvalue(1) in the SQL.append by:

```
IIF(cellvalue(1).Substring(0, 1) = "0",cellvalue(1).Substring(1),cellvalue(1))
```